# Remove item recusively from tree

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to create a tree component. But I dont know how remove a item recursively inside a tree.

Each item its created dinamically and I would like remove an item/branch of the tree in each level.

The problem is that when I select and item and has not children I have to find his parent and remove selected item. But If selected item has children, I have to find his parent, get all children of selected item, update all parentId of children, added to parent and remove selected item. Do all of that recursively and return updated array.

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, title: 'foo', children: [
    {id: 11, parentId: 1, title: 'bar',},
    {id: 12, parentId: 1, title: 'baz', children: [
      {id: 121, parentId: 12, title: 'qux'},
      {id: 122, parentId: 12, title: 'quz'}
    ]},
    {id: 13, parentId: 1, title: 'corge'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, title: 'grault'}
];

const id = 12;
console.log (removeElement(data, id));
```

Result should be:

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, title: 'foo', children: [
    {id: 11, parentId: 1, title: 'bar', children: [
      {id: 121, parentId: 11, title: 'qux'},
      {id: 122, parentId: 11, title: 'quz'}
    ]},
    {id: 13, parentId: 1, title: 'corge'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, title: 'grault'}
];
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: What item(s) do you want to remove? One at random?

Comment: you dont need parentId if you want a tree; use parentId if you want data to be an array of items { id, title, parentId }. For your question, looks like you want to remove item 12, and put its childrens in item 11, which is not a recursive logic ( childrens moving on the previous member - and this is tricky -, and not on the parent of the parent )

Comment: @D.Pardal: The id to remove is in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this can be done in a single function, it's a lot cleaner and less repetitive if you write this with [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).  Here we write two functions.  One removes the element from an array, replacing it with any children it might have.  The other processes a single object, removing the id from it (and from any of its children.)  Our main function here is `removeElement`, which will call `removeElementFromArray` on our input if the initial data is an array or call it against any children if the initial data is a plain object.

```js
const removeElementFromArray = (arr, id) =>
  arr .flatMap (
    o => o.id === id
      ? [... (o .children || []).map (o => removeElement (o, id))]
      : [removeElement (o, id)]
  )

const removeElement = (obj, id) => 
  Array .isArray (obj)
    ? removeElementFromArray (obj, id)
    : {... obj, ... (obj .children ? {children: removeElementFromArray (obj .children, id)} : {}) }


const data = [
  {id: 1, title: 'foo', children: [
    {id: 11, title: 'bar'},
    {id: 12, title: 'baz', children: [
      {id: 121, title: 'qux'},
      {id: 122, title: 'quz'}
    ]},
    {id: 13, title: 'corge'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, title: 'grault'}
];

console .log (removeElement (data, 121)) // 121 removed
console .log (removeElement (data, 12))  // 12 removed; 121 and 122 moved to 1
console .log (removeElement (data, 1))   // 1 removed; 11, 12, 13 moved to root
console .log (removeElement (data, 42))  // No change
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Loving the mutual recursion! This answer goes a long way in preserving the nodes without a `children` property. You are very good at matching an expected output to an exacting specification. I am not usually so tolerant/lenient to do this "v_v

Comment: @Thankyou: I'm not sure which is the better overall approach.  Yours is probably more pedagogically sound; mine might be more practical.  But maybe not, because, as shown by your answer, you often end up with something simpler as well.  It would remain simpler even if we updated it to keep the `children` node.

Comment: I took a shot at it but it involved me deviating from my normal `update`. Not sure how totally comfortable I am with it ...

Comment: There is a problem... remove branch but dont remove his children

Comment: @Javier: I'm not sure what you're saying.  This removes a branch an moves its children up to become children of its parent node.  That may not be what you want.  Looking again at the question, it looks as though you want to move them to the previous sibling of the parent.  That's more difficult, and leads to all sorts of interesting questions about what happens if you try to remove the first child of a node.  But you need to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "foo",
    children: [
      { id: 11, parentId: 1, title: "bar" },
      {
        id: 12,
        parentId: 1,
        title: "baz",
        children: [
          { id: 121, parentId: 12, title: "qux" },
          { id: 122, parentId: 12, title: "quz" },
        ],
      },
      { id: 13, parentId: 1, title: "corge" },
    ],
  },
  { id: 2, title: "grault" },
];

const id = 12;

function removeElement(data, id) {
  return data
    .filter((dt) => {
      return dt.id !== id;
    })
    .map((dt) => {
      if (dt.children) {
        return {
          ...dt,
          children: removeElement(dt.children, id),
        };
      }
      return dt;
    });
}
console.log(removeElement(data, id));
```

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott that mutual recursion is a great fit for this problem. I would divide the responsibilities slightly different however -

```js
const remove = (t = [], id = 0) =>
  t.flatMap(v => remove1(v, id))

const remove1 = ({ children = [], ...t }, id = 0) => // "remove one"
  t.id === id
    ? remove(children, id)
    : [ { ...t, children: remove(children, id) } ]

const data = [
  {id: 1, title: 'foo', children: [
    {id: 11, title: 'bar'},
    {id: 12, title: 'baz', children: [
      {id: 121, title: 'qux'},
      {id: 122, title: 'quz'}
    ]},
    {id: 13, title: 'corge'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, title: 'grault'}
];

console.log(remove(data, 121))
console.log(remove(data, 12))
console.log(remove(data, 1))
console.log(remove(data, 42))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In addition, this answer cares less about the optional `children` property and as a result it will add `{ ...t, children: [] }` to any `t` without `children`.

---

I admire Scott for his exacting approach and I wondered how I might be able to preserve the `children`-less leaf nodes -

```js
const identity = x => x

const update = (t = {}, k = "", f = identity) => // <- immutable update
  t[k] == null
    ? t
    : { ...t, [k]: f(t[k]) }

const remove = (t = [], id = 0) =>
  t.flatMap(v => remove1(v, id))

const remove1 = (t = {}, id = 0) => 
  t.id === id
    ? remove(t.children, id)
    : [ update(t, "children", c => remove(c, id)) ] // <-- update

const data = [
  {id: 1, title: 'foo', children: [
    {id: 11, title: 'bar'},
    {id: 12, title: 'baz', children: [
      {id: 121, title: 'qux'},
      {id: 122, title: 'quz'}
    ]},
    {id: 13, title: 'corge'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, title: 'grault'}
];

console.log(remove(data, 121))
console.log(remove(data, 12))
console.log(remove(data, 1))
console.log(remove(data, 42))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using filter:

```
  const removeNodeById = (nodeArray, id) => {
  return nodeArray.filter((node) => {
    if (node.id === id) {
      return false;
    } else if (node.children) {
      node.children = removeNodeById(node.children, id);
    }
    return true;
  });
};


console.log(removeNodeById(data, id));
```